# findViewById(R.id.progressbar) and static hell:

Tags: java, android

clipProgress resets a progress bar to zero:

```
public class Whatever extends Activity implements ListenerA, ListenerB {
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        ProgressBar myProgressBar;  
        int myProgress = 0;  

        public void clipProgress() {
            myProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);  
            myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);  
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            clipProgress();

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Duration.duration = 0;
                startRecording();

                new Thread(new Runnable(){  
                    @Override  
                    public void run() {  
                        while(myProgress<100){  
                            try{  
                                myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());  
                                Thread.sleep(50);  
                            }catch(Throwable t){  
                            }  
                        }  
                    }  
                }).start();  
            }

        Handler myHandle = new Handler(){  
            @Override  
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
                myProgress++;  
                myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);  
            }  
        };
    });
}
```

---

I have two different methods, below, where I suppose I could attempt to reset the progress bar to zero.  But they both reside in a different class entirely:

```
@Override   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {  
    Whatever.clipProgress();  //...which throws all kinds of red lines if I use this statement.
}
```

and

```
public void stopThis(){
    thing.stop();
    try {
        Whatever.clipProgress();  //...which throws all kinds of red lines if I use this statement.

        dos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Eclipse wants to apply "static" to various initializations in the Whatever class.  But those fixes just leave findViewById(R.id.progressbar) redlined.

I just want to reset the progress bar (which was started from within class 1) from class 2.  It's too much to ask for.

**UPDATE:**
Whatever is the starting point, the Android Activity.  Its handler, which I should have included in the above snip, right underneath onCreate is included in the snip below.  So more completely, and invoked from a button, is thus:

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Thread(new Runnable(){  
                @Override  
                public void run() {  
                    while(myProgress<100){  
                        try{  
                            myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());  
                            Thread.sleep(87);  
                        }catch(Throwable t){  
                        }  
                    }  
                }  
            }).start();  
        }

        Handler myHandle = new Handler(){  
            @Override  
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
                myProgress++;  
                myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);  
            }  
        };
```

Once that button is pressed a listener is produced:

```
    myTask = new Task();
    myTask.addTaskListener(this);
    myTask.execute(this);
```

It is inside the Task class:

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<Whatever, ArrayList<Float>, Void>{
...
    public void addTaskListener(TaskListener rl){
        this.rl = rl;
    }
...
```

that those two functions reside, one of which I'm hoping to use to stop the progress bar.

A task is designed elsewhere to shut down at exactly a constant number of seconds, and so I can hardcode 50 into that progress bar value on the sleep().  I just want to be able to shut the bar down back to zero earlier if I stop the task earlier.

Comment: You need an Whatever object in other class to access non static methods in Whatever class. That's basic.

Comment: Well I am a Java noob.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse warns you because you are accessing the `clipProgress` method in a static way (by calling `Whatever.clipProgress()`).

Also, you should only assign your progress bar once, so move

```
myProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
```

into your `onCreate` method.

You should probably pass the ProgressBar into the other class that needs to update it, and then do something like

```
myProgressBar.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
    }
});
```

this `post` method updates the ProgressBar on the UI thread, which is the only safe way to do it. Make sure you are only doing any of this if the activity with the ProgressBar is currently active.

You should also question whether you need to update the progress bar in this other class at all. I only see you updating the `myProgress` variable inside your handler, where you set the progress on the bar immediately after. Could you explain a bit more about the relationship between this other class and the activity with your progress bar?

Comment: When you say I should pass the ProgressBar into the other class that needs to update it, I have to ask:  "How?"

Comment: Your other class's constructor can accept a progress bar, such as `OtherClass(..., ProgressBar pbar) { ... }` and store it as a field, then access it later. But make sure that the original activity with the progress bar is still in the foreground when you do all of this.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try to do this and if I have any questions I'll post here again.

Comment: Craigy, thank you for your advice.  I'm trying to learn best practices and what you've imparted is really valuable that way.  I've added some additional info in the OP above.

Comment: So I guess what I'm asking is how do I pass what I need to into that Async Task object?

Comment: If you want to use an AsyncTask you should read up on it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html). I'm not really clear on what you want to achieve with this task. Is it just to update the progress bar every few milliseconds?

Comment: The Async task is doing something other than dealing with the exigencies of the progress bar.  The Async task is just where the stop code happens to be written.  There's one thing only which would have an effect on the already running progress bar in the Activity object:  stopping the task, for any reason (the task stop button was pressed, or the task timed out after hardcoded number of seconds).  I'll look at the links.  Thank you again for all your help.  I may have to write back again; it's relatively simple I know, but my Java and OOP isn't there yet.

Comment: OK, it looks like from your first link that something like myTask.execute(this, myProgress); would pass a myProgress View object as assigned by (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);?  Am I doing that right?

Answer (score 1):

This has more to do with Java programming and [instance / static methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) than with Android:

When you call `Whatever.clipProgress()` you're attempting to make a call to a static method call to `clipProgress` on the `Whatever` class, which is why Eclipse wants to add the `static` modifier.

However, `findViewById()` is an instance method (read the link above) on `Activity`, which is presumably some ancestor of your `Whatever` class. Static methods can't call instance methods statically, so even if you let Eclipse make `clipProgress` static, you need to call `clipProgress` on an *instance* of your activity.

Your other class needs to have a reference to the instance of the class on which you want to call `clipProgress()`. You should either pass in that reference to the other class, or as another poster noted, pass in a reference to the `ProgressBar` itself.

Then you can call e.g. `mWhatever.clipProgress()` or `progressBar.setProgress(0)`.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I regret that I stackoverflow lets me only check one answer (in this case the first similar response).

Comment: "Your other class needs to have a reference to the instance of the class on which you want to call clipProgress(). You should either pass in that reference to the other class, or as another poster noted, pass in a reference to the ProgressBar itself."  I don't understand how to pass a reference to the ProgressBar itself.  (Or "that" other reference whatever that is.)